# MVC - FilePathResult Not working in IIS6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6

in my project I have a few actions for specifically returning files (pdf/excel) within my view using FilePathResult. Unfortunately my hosting is currently in IIS6 and while the routing is working by using wildcard mapping for aspnet_isapi.dll the file links simply arent. Is there any way to get these to work with IIS6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, embarassingly enough, the problem was an incorrect path when I moved it to the IIS6 server so it works fine now I've corrected that.